# DataBinding with DataContext

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datacontext

what am I doing wrong here? I'm trying to create a `DataTemplate` using a collection inside the `DataContext` object, like the following:

C#:

```
namespace StackOverflowTests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new People();
        }
    }

    class People
    {
        public List<Person> PersonList { get; set; }

        public People()
        {
            this.PersonList = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person(){FirstName = "Carlo", LastName = "Toribio" },
                new Person(){FirstName = "Guy", LastName = "Incognito" }
            };
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <Window x:Class="StackOverflowTests.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" x:Name="window1" Height="300" Width="300">
        <Window.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="peopleTemplate">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="First Name" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonList.FirstName}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Last Name" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonList.LastName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid x:Name="gridMain">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource peopleTemplate}" />
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

I've done this a lot easier by using a class that inherits from `Collection<T>`, but for many reasons, I can't do that to solve this problem. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridMain">
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource peopleTemplate}" />
 </Grid>
```

Comment: This worked! I also had to take out the PersonList from <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonList.FirstName}" /> and <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonList.LastName}" /> in the DataTemplate. Thanks!

Comment: You also need to change peopleTemplate to just have {Binding FirstName} instead of PersonList